# Identity function on $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Consider $C[0,1]$ with metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ where $$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1 \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert dx$$ and
>
> $$d_2(f,g)=\Big(\int_0^1 \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert^2 dx\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$$
>
> Let $id$ be the identity map of $C[0, 1]$ onto itself
>
> Then $id:(C[0,1],d_2) \rightarrow (C[0,1],d_1)$ is continuous

Here's my try:

$\vert f(x)-g(x) \vert \in [0,1]$ implies $\vert f(x)-g(x) \vert^2 \leq \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert$

Hence $d_1(f,g) \leq d_2(f,g)$ and so the $id$ is Lipchitz of constant $1$, continuity follows!

Is this correct?

Comment: Well you don't know that $\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \in [0,1]$. The domain of the functions is $[0,1]$, but their range is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: ??? Yes, you edited the question, but you ignored the objection in the comment! After the edit the question still says $|f(x)-g(x)|\in[0,1]$, and that's still wrong, as User8128 pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. The standard proof uses Hölder's / Cauchy-Schwarz  inequality $$\left|\int_0^1 FG \, dx\right|\le \left(\int_0^1 F^2\, dx\right)^\frac12\left(\int_0^1 G^2\, dx\right)^\frac12$$
with $F=|f-g|$ and $G=1$.

Comment: From this inequality and  taking $\delta=\epsilon$,continuity follows. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ Kusma: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not correct, since it is not true in general that$$\bigl\lvert f(x)-g(x)\bigr\rvert^2\leqslant\bigl\lvert f(x)-g(x)\bigr\rvert.$$

Since $\operatorname{Id}$ is linear, in order to prove that it is continuous, all you need is to prove that there is a $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that$$(\forall f\in\mathcal{C}[0,1]):d_1(f,0)\leqslant kd_2(f,0).$$But\begin{align}d_1(f,0)&=\int_0^1\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^11\times\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dx\\&\leqslant\sqrt{\int_0^11^2\,\mathrm dx}\sqrt{\int_0^1\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert^2\,\mathrm dx}\\&=d_2(f,0).\end{align}

Comment: Oh! we use the fact in functional analysis, namely,  linearity, continuous at zero, continuous at all points are all equivalent. Am i right?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Yes, that's how I did it.

Comment: This helps too! thanks!